# How to express that the sausages are made with good quality meat with a shorter sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction

How to express that the sausages are made with good quality meat in the shortest way?

Can I say:

1. The sausages are good quality.
2. The sausages are of good quality.
3. These are good quality sausages.

Comment: Asking this question, I don't care about vocabulary or sausages themselves or rating systems. I care about nothing but grammar.  Sorry, I should have made it clear.

Answer (score 13):

All are correct and idiomatic.

The first two are very similar in meaning (the preposition phrase and the adjective are almost the same in meaning).  The third refers to "these" not "those" so is slightly more specific.

They don't have quite the same meaning as "...are made of good quality meat".  You could make a low-quality sausage from good quality meat, and you could make a high quality vegetarian sausage without any meat at all.

Comment: "They don't have quite the same meaning as "...are made of good quality meat"." How are they correct then? I'm not a native speaker but for me none conveyed the meaning of being made of good quality meat. You can have good sausages with low quality meat.

Comment: @Arsenal well really almost all the time you talk about sausages you will be talking about the taste and not the quality of the meat, which is almost always unknown.  There's a reason there's the famous saying: "Laws are like sausages, it is better not to see them being made.". Like I said in another comment, even if it's the greatest hot dog you've ever eaten you still have no interest in how it was made!

Comment: They are correct, because they are grammatially correct, and are ways to approve of the sausage. I've explained how the meaning is somewhat different.  I'd argue that it can't be a high quality sausage if it is made with low quality sausage meat.

Answer (score 4):

You could also say:

"These are choice, all-beef sausages."

"The sausages are grade-A [pork]."

Choice refers to the second best quality meat in the US Food & Drug Administration rating system (after Prime, which you could say as well, though "choice" also simply means very good), and "all-beef" means there are no other types of meat or filler. Grade-A means the best.

Comment: As a note for those possibly confused at the usage of ‘choice’ here instead of ‘prime’ as it’s the second best, ‘prime’ cuts of meat are rarely used in processed foods, being much more commonly used for things like steak, pork-chops, or cutlets (because if it’s already top quality, you do not need the spices and seasonings found in most processed products to make the meat taste better).

Comment: Partially no one would ever think you are referring to the usda grading system and would instead think you are using Internet slang, mainly because sausages are never sold that way.  Grade A would be understood as an idiomatic way of saying good.  It's true grade a, b is used for poultry (not pork though) but from a consumers perspective no one really thinks in those terms for poultry and pork (which is apparently graded on a 1-5 scale yet I have never ever seen this used at a consumer level)

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn not pork, only beef - in fact there have actually been lawsuits over trying to apply "prime" to things besides beef. But like you said, you will never see choice or prime used for beef sausages.  Using prime beef for a sausage would be like using filet mignon as a stew meat

Answer (score 2):

The OP would like a succinct description?

These are **[premium](https://www.lexico.com/definition/premium) sausages**.

From Lexico

> ### premium
>
> **2.2** [as modifier] Relating to or denoting a commodity of superior quality and therefore a higher price.
> ‘premium lagers’

An example of usage:

> …UK-based manufacturer and supplier of premium sausage and meat products.
>
> [we] deliver exactly what customers are looking for – Premium Quality, Premium Service and of course Premium Value.

Answer (score 1):

Bang up bangers, bro
This would be the Aussie version

Comment: Well, tasty, But good quality? Hard to tell.

Comment: @EthanBolker well sure but no one is talking about meat quality when they talk about sausages except if they are homemade (because otherwise you have no idea really).  I mean I've had some excellent hot dogs but when I say "this is a great hot dog" I'm sure as heck not talking about the meat's quality, which I very much prefer to know nothing about.

Comment: Shouldn't ‘bang-up’ be hyphenated?  Otherwise it's an instruction, about some bangers that need banging up (whatever that is)…

Comment: Snags surely!!!